# Is it possible to create a rule on Prometheus Alertmanager using moving average method?

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, moving-average

I need to create a rule on Prometheus Alertmanager or other solution using moving average method.

Situation:
In the last 30 minutes the quantity of access on login page is 1.000/minutes but if now it is 15% higher or lower it is time to throw an alert.

If it is possible, can someone give a sample of code?